# Is there a way to greatly improve the speed of this MySQL query used in the upgrade of Alfresco

Tags: mysql, alfresco

As part of the upgrade process Alfresco preforms this query

```
INSERT INTO ACT_HI_VARINST(
    ID_,
    PROC_INST_ID_,
    EXECUTION_ID_,
    TASK_ID_,
    NAME_,
    VAR_TYPE_,
    REV_,
    BYTEARRAY_ID_,
    DOUBLE_,
    LONG_,
    TEXT_,
    TEXT2_
    )
SELECT
    (@cnt := @cnt + 1),
    PROC_INST_ID_,
    EXECUTION_ID_,
    TASK_ID_,
    NAME_,
    VAR_TYPE_,
    REV_,
    BYTEARRAY_ID_,
    DOUBLE_,
    LONG_,
    TEXT_,
    TEXT2_
FROM ACT_HI_DETAIL AHD 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 177401 + 1) AS dummy
WHERE AHD.PROC_INST_ID_ not in (select PROC_INST_ID_ from ACT_HI_VARINST)
AND
    (AHD.PROC_INST_ID_ , AHD.NAME_, AHD.REV_, AHD.time_) IN
    (SELECT PROC_INST_ID_, NAME_, MAX(REV_), MAX(time_)
    FROM ACT_HI_DETAIL 
    GROUP BY PROC_INST_ID_ , NAME_);
```

It is taking over 12 hours to run.

Using explain on the query

```
explain SELECT
    (@cnt := @cnt + 1),
    PROC_INST_ID_,
    EXECUTION_ID_,
    TASK_ID_,
    NAME_,
    VAR_TYPE_,
    REV_,
    BYTEARRAY_ID_,
    DOUBLE_,
    LONG_,
    TEXT_,
    TEXT2_
FROM ACT_HI_DETAIL AHD
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 177401 + 1) AS dummy
WHERE AHD.PROC_INST_ID_ not in (select PROC_INST_ID_ from ACT_HI_VARINST)
AND
    (AHD.PROC_INST_ID_ , AHD.NAME_, AHD.REV_, AHD.time_) IN
    (SELECT PROC_INST_ID_, NAME_, MAX(REV_), MAX(time_)
    FROM ACT_HI_DETAIL
    GROUP BY PROC_INST_ID_ , NAME_)\G
```

results in

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
          id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
        type: system
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
        rows: 1
        Extra: 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
          id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: AHD
        type: ALL
possible_keys: ACT_IDX_HI_DETAIL_PROC_INST,ACT_IDX_HI_DETAIL_TIME,ACT_IDX_HI_DETAIL_NAME
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
        rows: 70669
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
          id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <subquery4>
        type: eq_ref
possible_keys: distinct_key
          key: distinct_key
      key_len: 976
          ref: alfresco.AHD.PROC_INST_ID_,alfresco.AHD.NAME_,alfresco.AHD.REV_,alfresco.AHD.TIME_
        rows: 1
        Extra: 
*************************** 4. row ***************************
          id: 4
  select_type: MATERIALIZED
        table: ACT_HI_DETAIL
        type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
        rows: 70669
        Extra: Using temporary
*************************** 5. row ***************************
          id: 3
  select_type: MATERIALIZED
        table: ACT_HI_VARINST
        type: index
possible_keys: ACT_IDX_HI_PROCVAR_PROC_INST
          key: ACT_IDX_HI_PROCVAR_PROC_INST
      key_len: 197
          ref: NULL
        rows: 41504
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 6. row ***************************
          id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: NULL
        type: NULL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
        rows: NULL
        Extra: No tables used
```

Adding an extra index

```
ALTER TABLE ACT_HI_DETAIL ADD INDEX `ACT_HI_DETAIL_MULTI` (PROC_INST_ID_, TIME_, NAME_);
```

resulted in halving the number of rows here

```
*************************** 2. row ***************************
          id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: AHD
        type: range
possible_keys: act_hi_detail_multi_1
          key: act_hi_detail_multi_1
      key_len: 195
          ref: NULL
        rows: 35761
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
```

The database is using innodb.
Setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size` up to 4G made no difference.

The table definitions:

```
MariaDB [alfresco]> desc act_hi_detail;
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID_           | varchar(64)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| TYPE_         | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| PROC_INST_ID_ | varchar(64)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| EXECUTION_ID_ | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TASK_ID_      | varchar(64)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ACT_INST_ID_  | varchar(64)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| NAME_         | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| VAR_TYPE_     | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| REV_          | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TIME_         | datetime      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| BYTEARRAY_ID_ | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DOUBLE_       | double        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LONG_         | bigint(20)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TEXT_         | varchar(4000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TEXT2_        | varchar(4000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)


MariaDB [alfresco]> desc act_hi_varinst;
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID_           | varchar(64)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| PROC_INST_ID_ | varchar(64)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| EXECUTION_ID_ | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TASK_ID_      | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NAME_         | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| VAR_TYPE_     | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| REV_          | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| BYTEARRAY_ID_ | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DOUBLE_       | double        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LONG_         | bigint(20)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TEXT_         | varchar(4000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TEXT2_        | varchar(4000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The current indexes are

```
MariaDB [alfresco]> show indexes from act_hi_detail;
+---------------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name                    | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| act_hi_detail |          0 | PRIMARY                     |            1 | ID_           | A         |       71244 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| act_hi_detail |          1 | ACT_IDX_HI_DETAIL_PROC_INST |            1 | PROC_INST_ID_ | A         |        3238 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| act_hi_detail |          1 | ACT_IDX_HI_DETAIL_ACT_INST  |            1 | ACT_INST_ID_  | A         |        5937 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| act_hi_detail |          1 | ACT_IDX_HI_DETAIL_TIME      |            1 | TIME_         | A         |        8905 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| act_hi_detail |          1 | ACT_IDX_HI_DETAIL_NAME      |            1 | NAME_         | A         |         147 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| act_hi_detail |          1 | ACT_IDX_HI_DETAIL_TASK_ID   |            1 | TASK_ID_      | A         |        5480 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| act_hi_detail |          1 | act_hi_detail_multi_1       |            1 | PROC_INST_ID_ | A         |         199 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| act_hi_detail |          1 | act_hi_detail_multi_1       |            2 | TIME_         | A         |         199 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| act_hi_detail |          1 | act_hi_detail_multi_1       |            3 | NAME_         | A         |         199 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [alfresco]> show indexes from act_hi_varinst;
+----------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name                     | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| act_hi_varinst |          0 | PRIMARY                      |            1 | ID_           | A         |       42358 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| act_hi_varinst |          1 | ACT_IDX_HI_PROCVAR_PROC_INST |            1 | PROC_INST_ID_ | A         |        1925 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| act_hi_varinst |          1 | ACT_IDX_HI_PROCVAR_NAME_TYPE |            1 | NAME_         | A         |         184 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| act_hi_varinst |          1 | ACT_IDX_HI_PROCVAR_NAME_TYPE |            2 | VAR_TYPE_     | A         |         219 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Are there more indexes that can be added or modifications than can be made to the query to greatly improve the speed?

Comment: The indexes look fine, and I don't see a reason why it would need 12 hours with tables < 100k rows, but since it is a one time query, maybe just let it run. Are there triggers on `ACT_HI_VARINST` that might slow it down? Are you able to edit the query? Although it is materialized, I guess the hash index does not work in the last subquery (with the `group by`) because the values can be null, so you might be able to optimize the query (or change the columns to `not null`, if they are not null anyway). Can you check if you have rows in  `act_hi_detail` where `PROC_INST_ID_` or `REV_` are `null`?

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks for your comments. There are no instances of PROC_INST_ID_ or REV_ being null. I altered the tables to make them not null but this made little difference, however as alfresco state that they require mysql 5.6 and I was running Mariadb 5.5 (Centos-7)  I upgraded to MariaDB 10.1. The update now takes a couple of seconds, so you were right to see no reason.